# Filtering a queryset in django for one of every type of entry

Tags: mysql, django

I've got a model which contains a foreignkey and some other things. The foreignkey is not a unique entry, which is to say a user could add his or herself to the database as many times as the user would like. I'd like to filter my queryset in such a way that generates a single entry for every type of  user. For example:

```
id | user_id (fk) | message
---+--------------+--------------
1  | 1            | hello!
2  | 5            | hey
3  | 1            | how are you?
4  | 5            | great!
```

Filtering with the criteria I have specified above would result in `(1, 5)`

Can't figure out which method to use, or if I'll have to write something on my own. Either way, insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Upon further review, I have determined that answer is the `distinct()` function when applied to a queryset :)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: That will only work if the user_id is the only field you're interested in. If you need to retrieve the `id` or `message` from the Message, distinct won't filter as you expect. You'll also need to specify the `values('user')` on the queryset, which will return `[{'id':1}, {'id':5}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase you want access to a model instance instead of just the foreign keys, you can do something like:

```
from django.db.models import Max

# get the latest id for each user_id (most recent)
latest = Message.objects.values('user_id').annotate(id=Max('id'))
Message.objects.filter(id__in=[m['id'] for m in latest])
```

This isn't as nice as what the raw sql equivalent is, since a select is returned, and then used as the basis for an IN () filter. It's fairly slow. The alternative is to write raw SQL, and you should avoid that.

```
-- here it is anyway

SELECT m.id, m.user_id, m.message
FROM Messages m
JOIN (
         SELECT user_id, max(id) as max_id
         FROM Messages
         GROUP BY user_id
     ) mm
ON m.id = mm.max_id
```